# How to work with excel file in memory

Tags: c#, excel

at the moment my current process is as followed. Query database - > Save file locally -> Open Workbook using Excel Interop Dll, Make Changes To Work Book, Save As using Excel Interop Dll. The reason for save as is because I require some addition settings so the file isn't set to read only.

The issue I'm coming across is that it's saving locally twice. First time is fine, second time a prompt will appear asking if I would like to override. I'm wondering how can I remove the Save File Locally process and have it in memory to work with? If I am able to work with the file in memory, I would have the prompt on `Save As` asking me if I would like to override the previous file.

Code:

```
//Save File Locally
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(saveFileDialog.FileName, Report.FileArray);

var fileLocation = saveFileDialog.InitialDirectory + saveFileDialog.FileName;

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

// Open Workbook Using Excel Interop Dll
Workbook wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(fileLocation);

Worksheet ws1 = wb.Worksheets.get_Item("English");

//Make Changes To WorkBook
ws1.Range["E5"].Value = StartDate;
ws1.Range["G5"].Value = EndDate;

// Save AS Using Excel Interop With shared settings to remove read only access
wb.SaveAs(fileLocation, AccessMode: XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlShared);

Process.Start(fileLocation);
```

Comment: You might want to use the Open XML SDK. It's a Linq API to the XLSX file. A lot less issues with it than calling the Excel COM API.

Comment: @DavidThielen Thanks for the recommendation, I will look into it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd better disable the prompt, to what I remember this is possible but it imply a lot of umnaged code...

Try this

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.MSProject.Application msProjectApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.MSProject.Application();
msProjectApp.DisplayAlerts = false;
```

**Edit**

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application msProjectApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
    msProjectApp.Visible = true; //show the application and not need to start a process
    msProjectApp.DisplayAlerts = false;
```

Comment: Just gave this a go and it doens't work. It's at the top level(Application) setting. The Alerts need to be at the workbook level

Comment: But If you permit an advice, if I were you, I would try to use a third party library to manipulate Excel. It will supress a lot of pain like this and this is only the beginning of the problems

Comment: Hi Mathieu, I was able to do this all with a third party dll, but it gave me unwanted warnings upon opening the excel file. By default .Visible is always false. BUT this allows me to replace `Process.Start(fileLocation);` if I were to set Visible to true, this solves my problem.

Comment: If you change your .Visible to true, I can make your answer as correct

Comment: I edit my answer. This what you were talking about ?

Answer (score 0):

```
//Save File Locally
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(saveFileDialog.FileName, Report.FileArray);

var fileLocation = saveFileDialog.InitialDirectory + saveFileDialog.FileName;

 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

// Open Workbook Using Excel Interop Dll
Workbook wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(fileLocation);

Worksheet ws1 = wb.Worksheets.get_Item("English");

//Make Changes To WorkBook
ws1.Range["E5"].Value = StartDate;
ws1.Range["G5"].Value = EndDate;

// Save Only
wb.Save();
```

Remove Process.Start

```
excel.Visible = true;
excel.DisplayAlerts = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you "own" the workbook and can set it up beforehand to play nice and are only loading in data, I find the OleDB Access SQL connection approach to be a better way to load raw data into SQL.